# Call stored procedure having both IN and OUT parameter in opencart

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, opencart

I have created a stored procedure for that sp there are 2 `IN` and 1 `OUT` parameters in mysql I call its as like

```
 SET @p0='101'; SET @p1='99'; 
 CALL `discountWithoutBoth`(@p0, @p1, @p2); 
 SELECT @p2 AS `discount_price`;
```

But I tried it in my opencart model but it got an error

```
We apologize for this problem and hope to have it resolved soon.
```

The code that I have tried in opencart is

```
$query_discount = $this->db->query("SET @p0 = '101';
                    SET @p1 = '99';
                    CALL `discountWithoutBoth` (@p0 , @p1 , @p2);
                    SELECT @p2 AS `discount_price` ;");
```

How can I achieve it in opencart?

Comment: How did you try that in Opencart? Is there anything written to your server's error log?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have updated the question with opencart code that I have tried.

Comment: What you've given there is not one query, but multiple ones. I don't think that `$this->db->query` supports this

Comment: @NicoHaase ya but how can i achieve this

Comment: which Opencart version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Try after splitting these query, and run one after another in sequence.

For example:

```
$query_discount1 = $this->db->query("SET @p0 = '101';");
$query_discount2 = $this->db->query("SELECT @p0 AS `discount_price` ;");
```

I am getting 101 for discount_price value.